# Table design for a commitment database

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to design a database to store commitments for Supervisors.  The interface will be through a web browser.

The issue I have is that each supervisor has different fields they track currently in their spreadsheets.  This is because each supervisor's group performs different types of work (commitments).

Should I have one commitment table with all the fields and keep tacking on new ones as more supervisors use this and request their fields?

Or Should I consider what the commitment item describes?   And instead have a generic commitment table and then have tables for each type of commitments to store the unique fields and use JOINS?  These extra tables may then only have a field or two.

A third option could be having just the separate tables for each type of commitment and have all the common fields (StartDate, EndDate, Description) repeated in each table.

Answer (score 1):

It depends: If the commitments are dynamic, meaning a supervisor can invent new ones then I would go for having a commitment type table containing all the different commitments similar to this:

```
 Table CommitmentType(Id, Description, ...)

 Table SupervisorCommitment(Id, CommitmentTypeId, SuperVisorId, StartDate, EndDate, ...)
```

This way supervisors can add new commitment types but they can also share them.

**Update**: If the commitments also have different fields then a more normalized version of the design would be to have also a `Field` table describing fields and either a CommitmentType to Fields relation table (in case it's m:n) or a commitment type id in the field table in case you don't want to share fields between commitments. Like this:

```
Table Field(Id, Name, TypeDescription, CommitmentTypeId)
```

or

```
Table Field(Id, Name, TypeDescription)
Table CommitmentTypeFields(FieldId, CommitmentTypeId)
```

This way you can create new commitments and new fields for each commitment.

You could also consider using a document oriented database like MongoDb or Cassandra which have a more flexible approach in the way the data is stored. However they have other disadvantages you should investigate and carefully weigh up before jumping on the "NoSQL" waggon.

**Update 2**: Storing the values could then go into a `CommitmentFieldValue` table like this:

```
Table CommitmentFieldValue(CommitmentTypeId, FieldId, Value)
```

Also: Just because you have the flexibility in your db design to create new commitment types and field does not mean you have to expose it to the UI.

Comment: scalability is desired so ability to add new commitment types is a good idea.  But where would the extra fields associated with the new commitment type go? If the new commitment type is to track the completion of a Budget Plan for Contract A, that supervisor may want a field for Contract Name, Author and Fiscal Year.  Another supervisor may want to track the completion of Widgets so they want fields for Part Name, Material type and Inspector First/Last Name.

Comment: @ChrisQue, I'd have to ponder your response some more but I still don't see where you would store the VALUE for the extra fields.  You are only creating extra look up tables.  And while I want scaleability, I don't necessarily need the ability for end users to create new Commitment Types.  I'd be out of a job!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like commitments in your scenario are mostly semi-structured/unstructured data. Have you thought about storing them as XML or maybe using a native XML database running alongside your relational database?

[eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/) is a good native XML database with a REST API that will allow you to easily query for commitments and display in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

My thinking would be to have a generic "commitments" table with all common data in there and a commitment type field. The advantage would be when you are displaying a list, you presumably would not need to join on the detail tables.

When you are looking for detail, you could join the correct table. It would even be possible to do something flexible like having the details in a key/value table. Where both the type of the detail field and the value are stored making it very easy to add new fields.

Comment: yeah I agree with having a generic commitment table.  My only concern was then the extra detail tables may only have a a field or two.   I'm not sure I like the key/value table idea.  I've read good and bad things about that approach.

Comment: Yeah, I have used the Key/Value approach and it is a pain, but sometimes it is the best solution. The nasty thing is you quickly find you should have a Key table, and a Values table with each row containing a KeyID as well as the value. Gets messy quick. Personally I would only choose that route if you wanted to give the end user the ability to add fields.

Answer (score 0):

The basic question is "how do I user a database to store polymorphic data?"; thus far, you've had all of the available answers that I'm aware of:

- Single table with all possible columns (SQL)
- One table with common columns, separate tables for variants (SQL)
- One table per variant (SQL)
- Entity/Attribute/Value (SQL)
- Document (NoSQL)

To choose the right solution, I recommend considering the kinds of queries your design is likely to have to support, and work out how you'd write those queries in each of the available models.

I'm guessing you might need queries like "find all supervisors with overdue commitments", "find all overdue commitments by type", "find supervisor with no commitments", "how many commitments do we have across the business, grouped by type?". Think about how you might answer them - maybe mock some things up on a dev box.

Eventually, you're going to have to consider a trade-off - flexibility in the future versus ease/speed of development today.